# Find a way to duplicate sources such as bxslide and ligfhtgallery to image slides

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm a first-year web publisher working in Korea. I use a translator, so please understand if the context of the writing doesn't connect naturally. I have a project in progress and I'm looking for a way to duplicate sources such as bxslide and ligfhtgallery on the image slide. You want to use image slides in the form of importing images into scripts Is there any way i can do?

```
<div id="expl_slide">            

            <!-- A jQuery plugin that adds cross-browser mouse wheel support. (Optional) -->
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
            
            <script src="/js/lightgallery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/picturefill/2.3.1/picturefill.min.js"></script>
            <script src="/js/lightgallery-all.min.js"></script>
            <!-- lightgallery plugins -->
            <script src="/js/lg-thumbnail.min.js"></script>
            <script src="/js/lg-fullscreen.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#lightgallery').lightGallery();                      
                    $('#m_lightgallery').lightGallery();
                });
            </script>

            <script>
                @foreach ($images as $data)
                img_array.push({'big':'/file/property/{{ $data -> idx }}_{{ $data -> image_idx }}_big.jpg','small':'/file/property/{{ $data -> idx }}_{{ $data -> image_idx }}_thumb.jpg','text':''});
                @endforeach
                //var wh = $('#expl_slide').width() - 676;
                image_frame_setting('expl_slide',1135,5);
                $(window).resize( function(){
                    if ($(window).width() < 1920) {
                        var wh = $('#expl_slide').width() - 676;
                        image_frame_setting('expl_slide',wh,5);
                    }
                });                                     
            </script>
        </div>
```